# Set of all linear combinations of a set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$$C = \{ ax^{3} + bx^{2} + cx + d \in \mathbb{R}_{3}[x]: a-2c+d = 0 \}$$
How can I write the set of all linear combinations of the vectors of $C$?

Comment: The set $C$ is in fact a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_3[x]$ and so the set of all linear combinations of the vectors of $C$ will be $C$ itself. Is there something more specific that you wanted?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani so I can write $C = <x^{3}, x^{2}, x, 1>$?

Comment: oh, no. That is not correct, it seems that you're looking for a basis for $C$. One such basis, in this case, would be $\{x - 2, x^2, x^3 - 1\}$.

Comment: That was it, I couldn't find the correct word for it in english!

Comment: Oh, great. Should I elaborate on *why* that is a basis as an answer or did you get that? (Note that the vectors you had written did not form a basis for $C$.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Could you show me process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107974/discussion-between-diogomgf-and-aryaman-maithani).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comments:
I claim that $B = \{x + 2, x^2, x^3 - 1\} \subset C$ is a basis for $C$. This means two things:

1. $B$ is a linearly independent.
2. $\operatorname{span} B = C$.

---

**Claim 1.** $B$ is linearly independent.
*Proof.* Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ be such that
$$a(x + 2) + bx^2 + c(x^3 + 1) = 0 + 0x + 0x^2 + 0x^3.$$

Comparing the coefficient of $x^3, x^2, x$, we see that $a = b = c = 0$. Thus, we are done.

---

**Claim 2.** $\operatorname{span} B = C.$
*Proof.* As $B \subset C$, it is clear that $\operatorname{span} B \subset C$. We show the reverse inclusion.
Let $p(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d \in C$.
By the definition of $C$, we must have
$$a - 2c + d = 0$$
or $d = 2c - a$.

Thus,
$$\begin{align}
p(x) &= ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + 2c - a\\
&= a(x^3 - 1) + b(x^2) + c(x + 2)
\end{align}$$

Hence, $p(x) \in \operatorname{span} B$. This concludes the proof.